# Program is arrays that uses search algorithms and I want it to make it user defined

Tags: java, oop, search, java.util.scanner

The first part is the main class and the second part is the subclass, i am using loops to make my program user defined. The problem is that i don't know how to received by using loops. and by that i want to make it less in codes because efficiency is good

```
import java.util.*;    
public class practice_oaapp{    
    public static void main(String[] args){             
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int maxSize = 100;
        int v = 0, hi; 
        //int vic[] = new int[1000]; 
        practice_oa oa = new practice_oa(maxSize);                        
        //Do While
        int a = 0;          
        do{              
            System.out.println("Provide Value: ");              
            v = in.nextInt();               
            oa.insert(v);               
            a++;            
       }            
    while(a<10);        
    }    
    }
```

This is the second part in which mostly it has the functions that I want to use.

```
public class practice_oa{           
    private long[] a;           
    private int nElems;
```

This is the constructor

```
public practice_oa(int max){            
    a = new long[max];          
    nElems = 0;    
}            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to what you're asking, but hopefully this helps. From what I can tell, you're doing fine with accepting the user input and storing it into v. Then, when you do oa.insert(v), do you actually have an insert method in your practice_oa class? If not, this is how I would recommend doing it:

```
public void insert(int inNum, int index){
    a[index] = inNum;
}
```

Add that method to your practice_oa class. Then, you'll want to change this line:

```
oa.insert(v);
```

to

```
oa.insert(v, i);
```

Including i, which represents the current index in the array, will allow your program to keep track of where it is in the array and add values there.

A final change you should consider making: since practice_oa is a subclass, you don't want to declare it public. This could give you errors when you try to compile, depending on how you have your code set up. Just remove the "public" keyword from the beginning of your class.

Hopefully this helps, and good luck coding!